# Get xAxis extremes before fire afterSetExtremes in higcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How to get current extremes displayed on chart before set new extremes?

On my xAxis I have event:

```
afterSetExtremes : function(e) {
    // do something ...
    afterSetExtremes(this);
}
```

Then the function afterSetExtremes:

```
function afterSetExtremes(e) {
    $.getJSON('from-sql.php?start='+e.min+'&end='+e.max+'&callback=?', function(data) {
        chart.series[0].setData(data);
    });
}
```

The code listed above is working correctly.
The object e have values like e.min, e.max, e.oldMin, e.oldMax, but min is equal oldMin, and max is equal oldMax.

I need help with this to prepare next feature in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook onto [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.setExtremes) event and get extremes of the axis via `axis.min/max` or `axis.getExtremes()`

```
xAxis: {
  events: {
    setExtremes: function (e) {
      console.log(this.min, this.max)
      console.log(this.getExtremes())
    }
  }
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/rqtwc6vx/

Comment: It's returning min and max values for new extremes (after fires method `afterSetExtremes`). I'm expecting min and max values before new extremes has been set.

Comment: New extremes in the example are 0, 5, old extremes are -0.11, 11.11 and these are logged in the console

Comment: Okay, maybe I didn't mention - I'm using Navigation bar and rangeSelector supplied with HighStock - there it is not working like your's example.

Comment: I checked this with stockchart and works exactly the same. If you have set liveredraw option (by default it is) and you are dragging the navigator the changes of extremes are small - you can see that it works here http://jsfiddle.net/fcwm5edy/ Maybe what you want is to save the axis extremes when the extremes start to change (e.g. on navigator mousedown)?

Comment: The option `liveRedraw` is a kind of workaround. Beter if solution will be independent of liveRedraw setting. So, my point is to save the axis extremes when the extremes start to change (e.g. on navigator mousedown).

Comment: So you need to attach mousedown event on your own to the navigator's elements, e.g. handlers and invoke axis.getExtremes() - http://jsfiddle.net/fcwm5edy/1/